# Facebook login not working in Live Server in ASP.NET MVC web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

Facebook login works fine when I test in local server but doesn't work in Live server.

I followed this [official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

Comment: You might need to whitelist the domain where your app works so that Facebook will allow login from that domain.

Comment: Hi @TasosK.  I have added those domain names in whitelist.

Comment: You need to install SSL certificate

Comment: I don't think we need to install SSL certificates for FB login authentication. Can you provide any reference that describes about installing SSL certificates for facebook login?